# handle multiple Buttons in a antd Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have one antd Form, inside it I have two submit buttons. I wanted to delete specific selected item when on click handle button. Control is not going into my onClick handle button function. For now I am trying to print in console.log. when I click on delete icon, in coonsole.log not printing anything.  Please someone help me on this.

sandbox link: https://we4fw.csb.app/

logic:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Select, Button } from "antd";
import { DeleteOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import CollegeList from "./CollegeList";

const { Option } = Select;

const Demo = () => {
  const collegesList = CollegeList;
  const [collegesSelectedList, setCollegesSelectedList] = React.useState([]);
  let count = 1;

  const handleRemoveList = (college) => {
    console.log("onClick", college);
  };
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="validate_other" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item name="select" label="Select">
        <Select
          placeholder="Please select a country"
          onChange={(college) => {
            setCollegesSelectedList([
              ...collegesSelectedList,
              collegesList[college].name
            ]);
          }}
        >
          {Object.keys(collegesList).map((college) => (
            <Option value={college}>{collegesList[college].name}</Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <label>List of institutes selected</label>
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid #b3e2d2" }}>
        <Form.Item>
          {collegesSelectedList.map((college) => (
            <ul key={college}>
            <li >
              {count++}.{college}{" "}
              <Button
                size="small"
                onClick={(college) => handleRemoveList(college)}
                icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
                danger
              />
            </li>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </Form.Item>
      </div>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 12,
          offset: 6
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You are accidentally referring to an `HTMLEvent` rather than the `college` itself**

**So you will need to remove that event reference like this:**

```
<Button
       size="small"
       onClick={(college) => handleRemoveList(college)}
       icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
       danger
/>
```

**TO:**

```
<Button
       size="small"
       onClick={() => handleRemoveList(college)}
       icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
       danger
/>
```

**And for removing your item from the list, you will need to update your `handleRemoveList`:**

```
const handleRemoveList = (college) => {
    setCollegesSelectedList(collegesSelectedList.filter((c) => c !== college));
};
```